# Android Olipad screen details

Tags: android, screen, tablet

Someone know which density has the tablet Oplipad Olivetti screen?

When i rotate the device in vertical position, it take the background image from the drawable folder, but when i rotate the device in horizontal position, the image result stretched. I tried to put the landscape background image in the drawable-land folder but it does't works.

Thaks

Comment: Olivetti Olipad 100 has a medium density screen, lo put the landscape background to the **drawable-land-mdpi** folder.

That's all.

Comment: I am using it with drawable-xlarge and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olivetti Olipad 100 has a medium density screen, lo put the landscape background to the **drawable-land-mdpi** folder. 
That's all.